# Auto fill column in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

Is there a way to fill a column in the attribute table with the same value, similar to a paste .  Is there something in the calculator that can be used to fill selected records/attributes.

Comment: I am assuming ARCGIS is the software. (see comment from Craig, and know you can modify your question anytime) please add appropriate software tag.

Comment: how can u auto fill a field (text)?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is YES!. That is the power of the calculator. 
In the attribute table, make your selection (directly on the map, selecting rows in the table or many other different ways). *Please make sure that you are in an edit session so that your changes can be undone. If outside an edit session, you have to live with (or fix) your mistakes.*

Right click on column name at the top to open the calculator. In the window that pops up, enter your value between quotation marks and select OK. This will automatically fill that value in that column for all the features/rows that are selected.

[image: calculator]

For more options, learn how to use the python radio button,
Here is a [tips and tricks pdf](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0405/files/fieldcalc_1.pdf) to help.
This resource will help with [some automation.](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/03/06/tips-and-tricks-accessing-feature-shape-in-calculate-field/) and can also be accessed from the right click on the column.
[image: right click here]
there are some nice links if you [hit google](http://www.google.com/search?q=esri%20calculator%20tips%20and%20tricks)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using ArcGIS for Desktop.

1. Start an editing session of the layer you want to edit.
2. Select all features you wish to edit in layer
3. Click the attributes button in the editor toolbar
4. Scroll to top of window and click on the layer name in attribute pane
5. Edit the field with content. This will update all selected records.

Note: This question was pretty vague. Make sure you are as clear as possible in your questions to help get good answers.

Comment: +1 for pointing out clear questions result in clear answers.